# how to implement current svgedit within webpack or vue project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, svg-edit

I failed to implement [SVG-Edit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit) into my project, can somebody show me how.

Here below is my failed solution:

- Vue2: copy the compiled `svg-edit` code into vue project's `public` folder, and set vue project as multiple-page project by *vue.config.js*.
- webpack4: install [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) and make some change to `webpack.config.js`.

My solutions are all failed because images or reference sources are misreferenced.